# vscode quick open "git checkout" shows no results

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

According to the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol), I can call "Quick Open" using "cmd + P", followed by "git checkout" to see the available branches to check out. I do not see this, as shown in the screenshot below.
[image: Screenshot of Quick Open]

However, if I open the "Command Palette" by "cmd + shift + P", and then type git checkout followed by Return, I see the correct list of available branches. Have I encountered a bug, or am I missing something?

Mac, latest vscode. Git works fine in the terminal, and vscode recognises the repository and I can commit and push changes successfully.

[image: Command Palette works]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is tracked by [issue 24408](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24408):

> > In VSCode 1.10 and earlier, I could do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, git checkout and it would offer me the list of branches. It was a very nice and smooth workflow.
> >
> > In VSCode 1.11, this seems to be gone. The new "`Git: Checkout to...`" is the replacement.

Explanation:

> Probably related to the new git SCM provider that is enabled by default. Please see [#24141](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/24141) and [Microsoft/vscode-docs#931](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/issues/931).
>   The new git SCM provider is not yet final so this should be reintroduced in future updates.
>
> **This behaviour is now gone since it's unavailable to extensions, which git has now become**.

In [VSCode 1.11](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/commit/e132decb87a306bb571e7aa7dc7954ace4a18396):

> ### Git extension enabled
>
> The [new Git source control extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_10#_contributable-scm-providers) is now enabled by default. This Git integration goes through the same extension points as third-party SCM providers. We're still working on the Git extension and if you'd like to go back to the previous version, you can run the `SCM: Disable Preview SCM` command to switch back.
>
> You can quickly tell if the Git extension is enabled by looking at the Activity Bar icon. The new SCM provider integration will show a merge icon instead of the Git icon:

[image: scm provider icon]

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you @VonC, for a quick answer!